# Hide/Show HTML element on mouseenter/mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A page has a `<li>`. When a customer enters the mouse into `<li>` area, another `<ul>` pops up (showing cart items). I can't figure out how to hide this `<ul>` when user moves the mouse out of `<ul>` area.

Here is jQuery code I tried:

```
$("#cartLi")
    .mouseenter(function () {
        $.post("/ShoppingCart/cartDropDown",
            function (data) {
                $('.cart-skeleton').replaceWith(data);
                $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');

            })
    });
$("#cartLi")
    .mouseleave(function () {
            $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');
    })

$(".cart-dropdown")
    .mouseenter(function () {
        $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');
    });

$(".cart-dropdown")
.mouseleave(function () {
        if ($('.cart-dropdown').css.display == 'inline-block') {
            $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<li class="catalogue-specials" id="cartLi">    
    <a href="#" id="btnLastOption">
 My Cart
</a>    
</li>
<ul class="cart-dropdown">
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you hide/show using plain css?

Comment: Almost same thing. My problem is first mouseenter/mouseleave is firing but second mouseenter/mouseleave not firing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `hide()` and `show()`.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#cartLi").mouseenter(function () {
    $.post("/ShoppingCart/cartDropDown", function (data) {
        $('.cart-skeleton').replaceWith(data);
    });
    $('.cart-dropdown').show();
});

$(".cart-dropdown").mouseleave(function () {
    $('.cart-dropdown').hide();
});
```

Comment: `$("#cartLi").mouseenter` firing but `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseenter` not firing at all.

Comment: The way I thought was that, as long as you can show through `$("#cartLi").mouseenter`, it wouldn't be necessary to show it again through `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseenter`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you need `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseenter` to fire also?

Comment: You're right. I probably don't need to show it again through `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseenter` but how do I hide ``$(".cart-dropdown")` I can't figure out since `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseenter` isn't firing at all

Comment: The code I wrote hides `$(".cart-dropdown")` when `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseleave` is fired. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah, sure, I just need to install TeamViewer.

Comment: what is your ID? by the way, come to this chat-room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193395/javascript-question

Answer (score 2):

Take a look this works. :) Check if this is your requirement or not?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cart-dropdown').hide();
});

$("#btnLastOption").mouseenter(function(){
    
        $('.cart-dropdown').show();
    });

$(".cart-dropdown").mouseleave(function(){
 $('.cart-dropdown').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="catalogue-specials" id="cartLi">    
    <a href="#" id="btnLastOption">
 My Cart
</a>    
</li>
<ul class="cart-dropdown">
<li>hsds</li>
<li>jshd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseleave` not firing

Comment: I can clearly see it working here but not working on my page. I set a debugger in the browser debugger to inspect but `$(".cart-dropdown").mouseleave` isn't firing when I'm leaving mouse out of `$(".cart-dropdown")` area. V strange

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a mockup JSON:

```js
$("#cartLi")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        myJson.forEach(item => {
          let html = `<li class="catalogue-specials"><a href="#">${item.id}. ${item.title}</a></li>`;
          $(".cart-dropdown").append(html);
          $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');
        })
      });
  })

$(".cart-dropdown")
  .mouseleave(function() {
    if ($('.cart-dropdown').css('display') === 'inline-block') {
      $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
```

```css
.cart-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="catalogue-specials" id="cartLi">
    <a href="#" id="btnLastOption">My Cart</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="cart-dropdown">
</ul>
```

The problem is `$('.cart-dropdown').css.display == 'inline-block'` is incorrect, it should be `$('.cart-dropdown').css('display') == 'inline-block'`.

And I also suggest that you start using fetch instead of `$.post()`, `$.get()`, `$.ajax()` - fetch is native, `$.something()` is not, and also has quite good browser support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

If you cannot use `fetch()` (e.g. because of structure, or other requirement / condition), then here's the snippet with `$.get()`:

```js
$("#cartLi")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $.get({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(response) {
        let html = ''
        response.forEach(item => {
          html += `<li class="catalogue-specials"><a href="#">${item.id}. ${item.title}</a></li>`;
        })
        $(".cart-dropdown").append(html);
        $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'inline-block');
      }
    })
  })

$(".cart-dropdown")
  .mouseleave(function() {
    if ($('.cart-dropdown').css('display') === 'inline-block') {
      $('.cart-dropdown').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
```

```css
.cart-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="catalogue-specials" id="cartLi">
    <a href="#" id="btnLastOption">My Cart</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="cart-dropdown">
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry I can't change to `fetch` right now cause of my whole logic.

Comment: You don't have to say sorry to me - it was just a suggestion. :) Then `$.post()` will do, and it's almost the same code.

Comment: I tried your code. So is everyone else suggesting almost the similar code but for some strange reason `$(".cart-dropdown")
  .mouseleave` isn't firing here. I set a debugger point inside browser to check if it fires at all or not but no luck. It's simply not firing.

Comment: I suggest you do a test - just a `.mouseleave(function() {console.log('mouseleave');})`. If this doesn't fire, then something strange is happening - probably you have an error (or a silent error) in your code.